# reloading php file with static urls

Tags: php

I have a PHP file with a few variables that load URLs, e.g.:

```
<? php
$URL_1 = "http://local.web.site/my-test-page.html";
$URL_2 = ...;
...
?>
```

These are used on a different page inside a link:

```
<a href="<?=$URL_1?>">Click here</a>
```

I updated one of the URLs, but the link is still pointing to the previous URL.

How do I get the page to show the updated URL?

Comment: Are you sure you're not reassigning an old value after the updated one?

Comment: Are you sure you are not getting a cached version of you page?

Comment: @TomWalters - I think this is the only file that's setting this variable, but I'll double-check to make sure.

Comment: Delete cache from browser settings.

Comment: Press F5, and check for example with FireBug if the request goes to your server, or it is served from browser-cache.

Comment: @ZoltánTamási - used Ctrl+F5, and it loaded with 200 OK.

Comment: @AdamV See Zoltan's comment above for best way to verify if your page is being served from browser cache.

Comment: @MikeBrant - I can't install Firebug here (it's my work PC). Used Fiddler to verify the status code.

Comment: Are you sure you're editing the file that's being served out and not a copy somewhere else?

Comment: @dlp - I rechecked; the file I edited (example #1 above) was the only file that sets the variable that I'm using in the other pages.

Comment: Can you run a search in the file to find other assignments to this variable? Perhaps you are editing the wrong file (disconnected FTP client, wrong location, saving under old name), or some other happens-to-everyone mistake?

Comment: @NicolasBouliane - that's what I did; I grep'd for all references to that variable anywhere in the folder, and the file I updated was the only one that sets that variable.

Comment: It's a primitive approach, but in such bizarre situations I used to ensure myself if my change is in effect by putting an echo "foo" in front of the particular line. If you see "foo" in your browser, then the script is up to date, if you don't, then you probably miss somethings.

Comment: @ZoltánTamási - thanks for the idea! I put a "foo" in my page, and it turns out the link must be hardcoded somewhere else, because the "foo" showed up above an updated link I wasn't even looking at!

Answer (score 1):

In order to prevent the page load from cache you may write the following your header of the page:

```
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0">
```

Setting the content to "0" tells the browsers to always load the page from the web server.